# How to limit number of characters with jQuery / JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a snippet of code in my jQuery:

```
<li> Speed MPH: ' + val.speed_mph + '</li>\
```

which is pulled from a JSON endpoint and displays as such in the browser:

Speed MPH: 7.671862999999999

How would I go about limiting the amount of characters in the output? I have tried adding to the string:

```
.substring(0;4)
```

Obviously this is not working. Would I need to create a variable? I have tried this but not too sure how to go about displaying it afterwards.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show x many decimals, you shouldn't be using substring (as it's a little unclear, especially once you hit numbers > 9).  Instead you should use something like `toPrecision`:

```
var speed = 7.632234;
console.log(speed.toPrecision(3));
```

Note that this sets the TOTAL number of characters (which may be what you want).  If you want digits after the decimal, then you should use `toFixed` like Alex Kinnee suggests.

Comment: Cool! I did not know about `toPrecision()`.

Comment: @AlexKinnee Yeah, it matches more closely the substring call, but I imagine toFixed is more common and may actually be what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `val.speed_mph` is a number and not a string, you can use `parseFloat`, along with JavaScript's `Math` functions, to format this number.

`parseFloat(Math.round(num3 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);` will give you 2 decimal places.

If your value is not a number, but is a string, `parseFloat()` converts your stringto a number. `toFixed(2)` makes it 2 decimal places.

`Math.round()` rounds your number instead of just chopping it off.